# Why is my LSTM in tensorflow learning so slowly and badly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

This program reads a text file RNNtext.txt, creates one-hot vector representation for all the data, trains the LSTM with the data and displays a bunch of sampled characters every now and then. However, even looking at the [cost vs iterations graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snBzG.jpg) shows that it's learning very very inefficiently. Honestly, the raw code (numpy) for the LSTM I have does a MUCH better job. It's not only faster but it produces mostly meaningful words. This produces gibberish only. Where is my mistake? I really am out of ideas and I can't seem to find where it is logically wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Reading RNNtext.txt file
direc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
data = open(direc + "/RNNtext.txt", "r").read()

# Array of unique characters
chars = list(set(data))

num_hidden = 80
iterations = 1000
display_iteration = 100 # Sample when iteration % display_iteration == 0
sample_size = 250
batch_size = 120 # batch size or the number of time steps to unroll RNN
alpha = 0.01 # Learning rate

#Vocabulary and text file sizes
vocab_size = len(chars)
data_size = len(data)

# Bijection from a unique character to an index
char_to_ix = {}
# Bijection from an index to a unique character
ix_to_char = {}

for j in range(vocab_size):
    char_to_ix[chars[j]] = j
    ix_to_char[j] = chars[j]


# Transforming all characters to indices    
data_ix = [char_to_ix[ch] for ch in data]


train_data = [] # This will contain one-hot vectors
for k in range(data_size):
    # Representing each index/character by a one-hot vector
    hot1 = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1))
    hot1[data_ix[k]] = 1
    train_data.append(hot1)



X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, vocab_size, 1]) #Number of examples, number of input, dimension of each input
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, vocab_size])


cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype = tf.float32)
output = tf.transpose(output, [1, 0, 2])


weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, vocab_size]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vocab_size]))

prediction = tf.matmul(output[-1], weight) + bias
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=target))

optimizer = tf.train.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(alpha)
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cost)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


ARR = [i for i in range(vocab_size)] # for extracting index by probabilities in np.random.choice()

ITER = []
COST = []

p = 0 # p will be iterated by batch_size steps
for i in range(iterations):
    if p + batch_size >= data_size:
        p = 0

    # sweeping through data one-hot vectors 
    inp, out = train_data[p:p+batch_size], train_data[p+1:p+batch_size+1]
    out = np.reshape(out, [-1, vocab_size])

    c = sess.run(cost, {X: inp, target: out}) # calculating cost for plotting later
    COST.append(c)
    ITER.append(i)

    sess.run(minimize, {X: inp, target: out})

    # displaying sample_size number of characters with random seed
    # doesn't affect training
    if i % display_iteration == 0:
        seed = np.random.randint(0, vocab_size)
        CHARS = []
        for j in range(sample_size):
            x = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1))
            x[seed] = 1
            x = [x]
            pred = sess.run(prediction, {X: x})[0]
            pred = np.exp(pred) / np.sum(np.exp(pred))
            pred = pred.ravel()

            seed = np.random.choice(ARR, 1, p = pred)[0]
            ch = ix_to_char[seed]
            CHARS.append(ch)
        TXT = ''.join(CHARS)

        print("-------------------------------------------------")
        print(TXT)
        print("Iteration: ", str(i))

    p += batch_size
sess.close()
plt.plot(ITER, COST)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: Added numpy code for comparison

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
direc = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

readFile = open(direc + "\RNNtext.txt", 'r')

data = readFile.read()
readFile.close()


chars = list(set(data))
data_size, vocab_size = len(data), len(chars)
print(chars)
print("Vocabulary size: " + str(vocab_size))
char_to_ix = {}
ix_to_char = {}

for j in range(len(chars)):
    char_to_ix[chars[j]] = j
    ix_to_char[j] = chars[j]

hidden_size = 80
batch_size = 120
alpha = 0.1
sample_size = 250
iterations = 1000
display_iteration = 100



Wxh = np.random.randn(hidden_size, vocab_size)*0.01 # input to hidden
Whh = np.random.randn(hidden_size, hidden_size)*0.01 # hidden to hidden
Why = np.random.randn(vocab_size, hidden_size)*0.01 # hidden to output
bh = np.zeros((hidden_size, 1)) # hidden bias
by = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1)) # output bias


def sample(hid, seed, weights, sample_size):
    X = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1))
    X[seed] = 1
    CHARS = []
    ARR = [i for i in range(vocab_size)]

    for t in range(sample_size):
        hid = np.tanh(np.dot(Wxh, X)  + np.dot(Whh, hid) + bh)
        y = np.dot(Why, hid) + by
        prob = np.exp(y) / np.sum(np.exp(y))
        prob = prob.ravel()
        ix = np.random.choice(ARR, 1, p=prob)[0]
        CHARS.append(ix_to_char[ix])
        X = np.zeros((vocab_size, 1))
        X[ix] = 1
        TXT = ''.join(CHARS)
    return TXT

LOSS = []
ITER = []
p = 0

mWxh, mWhh, mWhy = np.zeros_like(Wxh), np.zeros_like(Whh), np.zeros_like(Why)
mbh, mby = np.zeros_like(bh), np.zeros_like(by) # memory variables for Adagrad

smooth_loss = -np.log(1.0/vocab_size)*batch_size # loss at iteration 0
hprev = np.zeros((hidden_size,1))


for i in range(iterations): ## just time passing by

    dWxh = np.zeros_like(Wxh)
    dWhh = np.zeros_like(Whh)   
    dWhy = np.zeros_like(Why)   
    dbh = np.zeros_like(bh) 
    dby = np.zeros_like(by)     


    if p+batch_size >= len(data) or i == 0:
        hprev = np.zeros((hidden_size,1))
        p = 0

    inputs = [char_to_ix[ch] for ch in data[p:p+batch_size]]
    targets = [char_to_ix[ch] for ch in data[p+1:p+batch_size+1]]

    HID = {}
    X = {}
    Y = {}
    P = {}
    HID[-1] = np.copy(hprev)

    loss = 0

    ##======FORWARD======##
    for t in range(len(inputs)):
        X[t] = np.zeros((vocab_size,1))
        X[t][inputs[t]] = 1

        HID[t] = np.tanh(np.dot(Wxh, X[t])  + np.dot(Whh, HID[t-1]) + bh) # inp -> X
        Y[t] = np.dot(Why, HID[t]) + by # tanh
        P[t] = np.exp(Y[t]) / np.sum(np.exp(Y[t]))
        loss += -np.log(P[t][targets[t]][0])
    dhnext = np.zeros_like(HID[0])
    ##======BACKPROP======##
    for t in reversed(range(len(inputs))):

        dy = np.copy(P[t])
        dy[targets[t]] -= 1
        dh = (np.dot(Why.T, dy) + dhnext)*(1-HID[t]*HID[t]) 
        dx = np.dot(Why.T, dy)*(1 - HID[t]**2)

        dWhy += np.dot(dy, HID[t].T) 
        dWhh += np.dot(dh, HID[t-1].T) 
        dWxh += np.dot(dh, X[t].T) 
        dby += dy 
        dbh += dh 

        dhnext = np.dot(Whh.T, dh)

    ##=====================##
    hprev = HID[-1]
    smooth_loss = smooth_loss * 0.999 + loss * 0.001
    for dparam in [dWxh, dWhh, dWhy, dbh, dby]:
        np.clip(dparam, -1, 1, out=dparam) # clip to mitigate exploding gradients


    for param, dparam, mem in zip([Wxh, Whh, Why, bh, by], 
                                [dWxh, dWhh, dWhy, dbh, dby], 
                                [mWxh, mWhh, mWhy, mbh, mby]):


        mem += dparam * dparam

        param += -alpha * dparam / np.sqrt(mem + 1e-8) # Adagrad
    if i % display_iteration == 0:
        print(str(i))
        weights = [Wxh,Whh,Why,bh,by]
        seed = inputs[np.random.randint(0,len(inputs))]
        TXT = sample(HID[-1], seed, weights, sample_size)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        print(TXT)
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        with open(direc + "\RNNout.txt", 'w') as writeFile:
            writeFile.write(TXT)
    ITER.append(i)
    LOSS.append(loss)

    p += batch_size
best_text = sample(HID[-1], inputs[0], weights, sample_size)


plt.plot(ITER, LOSS, linewidth = 1)
plt.show()

writeFile.close()
```

Comment: not enough information provided. How long did you train for? What was the starting and ending training/verification costs? you need to provide details about the system you are working with to get an informed answer. almost all RNN models take a decent amount of time and compute to train to the point where it's not just spitting out jibberish.

Comment: As you can see from the code I set the iteration number equal to 1000. This takes around a minute or so to train. That's not the point though. I can read the same exact file with the same hyper parameters of the LSTM in raw code (written in numpy) and it starts producing words after 10 seconds. I left this tensorflow implementation overnight and in the morning it still was producing gibberish.

Comment: Well, when you say "producing words" we don't know what it means. What data are you training on and what is the goal? Can we see your numpy implementation? I will bet you that your "raw code" implementation is just not doing the same thing.

Comment: I edited my OP. I included basically Andrej Karpathy's famous code for a simple RNN. I did re-implement it for an LSTM as well but it's a bit longer (and for one layer does similarly well like the simple RNN in numpy). Speaking of data, I don't see why do you put such emphasis on it - I just copy-pasted the first Latin-characters-only paragraph I found which is ~1200 characters in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, doh... looks like you are not re-using the state! How is LSTM (state machine) supposed to work properly if you are not maintaining the state?

To me this looks like a red flag:

```
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype = tf.float32)
```

the second output from `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` is the latest state after the given sequence has been processed. Looks like you are explicitly ignoring it and not re-feeding it into each following iteration of training in `sess.run(...)` (and hence your `dynamic_rnn` doesn't have the `initial_state` parameter).

I would highly recommend changing that part of your code before looking any further.

Also, I don't know what your data looks like, but your feeding and batching strategy needs to be such as to make sense out of this whole state-passing exercise. Otherwise, once again, it will just produce gibberish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that tf.nn.dynamic_rnn() updates the state during the training by default. Printing the state in sess.run() confirms that it changes throughout iterations.

Comment: Yes, it updates the state for each time step within the sequence that you feed into it. But presumably you want to cal dynamic_rnn multiple times, over multiple epochs/etc.? In that case, the state that comes out of each call to dynamic_rnn needs to be re-fed into it at the following step. That's for training. For predictions, it's the same thing: you feed an X of say 10 steps, it generates an output, and then you re-feed that output to generate another output. All of this needs to maintain state carefully. Your code doesn't do it, I don't think

Comment: By the way, this is what I meant when I said you have to make sure your feeding and batching needs to be done to make sense around this strategy (i.e. if you chop-up your training data-set into batches and feed it over multiple epochs). You need to make sure that each call to dynamic_rnn passes along the state to the next call in a way that makes sense (i.e. that dynamic_rnn sees repeatedly the sequences of X that make sense in relation to each other, sequentially)

Comment: Alright. Makes sense that it re-writes the state as zeros across different batches. I'll try to make it "remember". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, I would suggest these two initial steps to try to improve the model.

1. Increase the number of iterations, Recurrent Neural Networks work differently than other deep arhitectures and could need maybe an additional order of magnitude in iteration number, to settle.
2. Play with the seeds: from my experience in order to get meaningful sequences can depend on the quality of the used seeds.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Firstly, I left the tensorflow implementation train the LSTM for 100,000 iterations and it was producing worse results in the end than the raw numpy simple RNN was after 500 iterations.
Secondly, the seeds are initialized randomly in both tensorflow and numpy codes. I don't think it makes a big difference when the sampling size is quite large and I use only Latin alphabet for training.